# Display certain content of a web page via PHP

Tags: php

I'm using WAMP for my projects, but I'm not satisfied with the original index.php.
I want to display the projects folder on the WAMP index page. Here's what I've managed to think about:

```
<? 
$sisis = file_get_contents('projektit');
echo $sisis;
?>
```

But this won't do anything actually. Here's the projects folder displayed in browser:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Index of /projektit</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Index of /projektit</h1>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <img src="/icons/blank.gif" alt="[ICO]">
                </th>
                <th>
                    <a href="?C=N;O=D">Name</a>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <a href="?C=M;O=A">Last modified</a>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <a href="?C=S;O=A">Size</a>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <a href="?C=D;O=A">Description</a>
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="5">
                    <hr>
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top">
                    <img src="/icons/back.gif" alt="[DIR]">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="/">Parent Directory</a>
                </td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td align="right">-</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top">
                    <img src="/icons/folder.gif" alt="[DIR]">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="CCCKauppa/">CCCKauppa/</a>
                </td>
                <td align="right">24-Aug-2012 22:43</td>
                <td align="right">-</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="5">
                    <hr>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>

</html>
```

How would I display the links only on this page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand your question, you want to generate directory listing with links. (If I misunderstood, please just comment answer)

## For PHP 5 and later

you could use [scandir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) (PHP5 function) and do something like

```
<ul> 
<?php 
$dir = '/projektit'; 
$files = scandir($dir); 
foreach($files as $ind_file){ 
?> 
<li><a href="<?php echo $dir."/".$ind_file;?>"><?php echo $ind_file;?></a></li> 
<?php 
} 
?> 
</ul>
```

I haven't tested it so may need some tweaking.

## For older PHP versions

If that doesn`t work, you need the [opendir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php), [readdir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php) & [closedir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.closedir.php) functions.

```
$dir = opendir('projektit/'); 
echo '<ul>';
while ($read = readdir($dir)) 
{

if ($read!='.' && $read!='..') 
{ 
echo '<li><a href="files/'.$read.'">'.$read.'</a></li>'; 
}

}

echo '</ul>';

closedir($dir);
```

## Update

[Here is ready to use directory lister](http://goo.gl/YVC2V) with returning to parent folder functionality. [Demo](http://goo.gl/wHlSp)

Comment: I'll try the scandir, as I'm using PHP 5.4

Comment: Yeah, will do that when it's possible. However, I'd like to only show the folders, as this will show the ../ also in the `<ul>`

Answer (score 1):

You can use scandir to get all files in a folder.

```
$scanned = scandir($your_path);

// if you want to display only folders then you can:
// But please notice that array filter with anonymous function is available since PHP 5.3.0
$scanned = array_filter($scanned, function($el) { if (strpos($el, '.') === false) return $el; });

foreach($scanned as $folder)
   echo $folder;
```

Basically, the idea is to get all files in a folder (`$your_path` in this case), and remove those files with extensions. So, you'll have only folders at hand.